# Weird Behavior of ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql

hello mates hope you having a nice day, i have a really weird problem with getting data from Mysql database in Java , in the method here :

```
 ResultSet tableExistence;
 .
 .
 .

    while (tableExistence.next()) {

          System.out.println("before : "+tableExistence.getInt(MyHttpServer.COL_ID));

        if(tableExistence.getString(MyHttpServer.COL_STATUS).equals(MyHttpServer.STATUS_AVAILABLE)){

          System.out.println("after : "+tableExistence.getInt(MyHttpServer.COL_ID));    

       ...
 }
```

weirdly the value of the "before" is for the right value of the id , but after  the if method, the value of "after" returns some thing like 1234125151231 , any idea why is this problem ?!!!!

Comment: The docs do say "For maximum portability, result set columns within each row should be read in left-to-right order, and each column should be read only once." Admittedly it's still somewhat surprising, but...

Comment: wow, 2 years of working with mysql in java and first time i see such thing ! probably the problem is brighter in the latest version of jdbc

Comment: any way, this looks the answer !!! thanks post it as answer so i can accept thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The [`ResultSet` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) states:

> The docs do say "For maximum portability, result set columns within each row should be read in left-to-right order, and each column should be read only once."

So technically, it's somewhat reasonable. However:

- I would actually expect that any modern, well-supported database would allow you to access the columns in an arbitrary order, multiple times
- Just returning an incorrect value rather than throwing an exception to indicate the problem is pretty nasty

One explanation could be if you're fetching a clob or blob - the driver *may* decide in that case that "left to right only" is more reasonable, to avoid having to keep too much data in memory. It's still not great that it just returns corrupted data though.

So while this is a *possible* answer, I would also:

- Check that neither the connection nor the `ResultSet` is being used from multiple threads concurrently
- Check that you're using a recent version of the MySQL driver

Comment: nah i never using blob or clob in data base , i suspect it has some problem with the jdbc driver or the hikkariCP that i am using. thanks any way

Comment: yep appearantly problem was with the jdbc 5.1.5 , changed to 5.1.10 problem went away

Comment: @iamreza: Excellent! Glad to hear it :)